# Refactoring of .NET code to comply with coding standards

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, refactoring, naming-conventions

we have a code base (VB.NET and C#) and a new coding standard. Do you have suggestions of tools that can move through a project and rename parameters/fields/properties/metothods etc according to the new coding standard.

It might for example need to change parameters into camel-case etc. One would imagine that parameters and local fields/variables are more easily renamed due to their local scope.
I have looked at ReSharper but haven't found that it performs this task.

Comment: ReSharper has very good rename refactoring tools, as does Visual Studio.

Comment: ReSharper is your best friend with this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, aggree on ReSharper being a great tool but I don't think it will do a "batch" cleanup according to a specified coding standard. If it can, please let me know how it is done!

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a job for [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) with the [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) plugin. Here's an example:

Parameters name camelCasing :

[image]

fields renaming :

[image]

Solution Cleanup :

[image]

Comment: Ok, since you seem to have tried it, is this possible on a project and/or file basis, so that I don't have to process each instance?

Comment: Yes. It's possible using ReSharper's code cleanup (it is profile based and you can cleanup entire solutions.

Comment: So is this StyleCop, and is it like hinted in the answer below already included in Visual Studio?

Comment: StyleCop is for C# only (correct me if I'm wrong), and even though we are moving to C# almost all of the code that we need to refactor is VB.NET.

Comment: @nobba For VB.Net you have [Submain CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx) and [SSW Code Auditor](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/CodeAuditor/) But I can't vouch for any of them as I never tried them. (They're not free)

Answer (score 0):

Several options come into mind:

- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx)

Depending on the version of your Visual Studio you have StyleCop built into it and you can enforce checkin rules in TFS that the code itself must comply with the guidelines before something can be checked in.

Something else: why did you change your coding standards all of a sudden and apparently go through all of your existing/production code to change it. I can imagine you want to enforce the new guidelines in new applications that need to be built or just started out.

Comment: We have VS2010 Premium. To answer your question, we are not so much changing the entire standards but let's just say there are mixed standards to some extent and we haven't decided to alter the entire code base but if we do find a tool that can do this then it might possibly be done.